# Adding ClientDetails Fields in PayPal preapproval request message

Tags: paypal

[This guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) on requesting preapproval key talks about ClientDetails Fields but the example does not have them, so my question is how do I add ClientDetails Fields to the request message? I want to pass the clients username so I can get it back from IPN when client approves payment, so I know which client that approval belongs.

```
curl -s --insecure
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username"
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password"
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature"
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: app_id"
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval  -d
"cancelUrl=http://your_cancel_url
&currencyCode=USD
&endingDate=2009-12-13T08%3A00%3A00.000Z
&maxAmountPerPayment=200.00
&maxNumberOfPayments=30
&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=1500.00
&pinType=NOT_REQUIRED
&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
&returnUrl=http://your_return_url
&startingDate=2009-07-13T07%3A00%3A00.000Z
&senderEmail=sender@domain
```

EDIT :

The actual NVP string :

```
cancelUrl=http://www.example.com/members/try-again/
&currencyCode=USD
&endingDate=2017-12-13T08%3A00%3A00.000Z
&maxAmountPerPayment=200.00
&maxNumberOfPayments=30
&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=1500.00
&pinType=NOT_REQUIRED
&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
&returnUrl=http://www.example.com/members/add-payment/
&startingDate=2015-12-27T07%3A00%3A00.000Z
&ipnNotificationUrl=http://www.example.com/members/ipn.php
&customerid=testid
```

Comment: Looks like you just be able to add the customerId parameter to your NVP string.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I did, it wasn't returned by IPN

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct IPN?  With Adaptive Payments there are actually 2.  One is app specific and the other is transaction specific.  I don't see the ipnNotificationUrl specified in your request, so I'm guessing you're just getting IPNs from what is configured in your PayPal account profile..??  That would be transaction specific.  I think the customerId would come back in the app specific IPN, which you have to set in the request.

Comment: I did send the ipn url with the preapproval request, edited the question and added the actual NVP string

Comment: Ok, it could be the other way around then.  Do you have IPN setup in the seller profile, too, so that it would trigger that separate IPN?

Comment: In the sandbox account, no IPN url is set.

Comment: Set one there, and make sure your IPN handler can handle both IPNs correctly.  Maybe start with just saving a basic log of the IPN data (which it sounds like you may already have.)  Then, with the ipnNotificationUrl set in the Preapproval request, and IPN configured in the receiver's account, you'll end up getting 2 different IPNs from the same transaction.  One of them should have that data you're after.